# how do I reset a input in python

Tags: python

so i have this code that basically consists of you asking questions, but i have it so the input answers the question, so you can only ask one question, then you have to reset the whole thing again and again, and i have it to ask you your name first so i want a loop that ignores that.

```
    print("hello,what is your name?")
name = input()
print("hello",name)

while True:
    question = input("ask me anything:")
    if question == ("what is love"):
        print("love is a emotion that makes me uneasy, i'm a inteligence not a human",name)
        break
    if question == ("i want a dog"):
        print("ask your mother, she knows what to do",name)
        break
    if question == ("what is my name"):
        print("your name is",name)
        break
```

Comment: did you try getting rid of the `break` statements? You'll probably want to add an exit condition (i.e. `if question == ("Quit"): break`

Comment: Please see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 3):

Get rid of the `break`s, so the loop keeps prompting for new questions. For performance, change the subsequent `if` tests to `elif` tests (not strictly necessary, but it avoids rechecking the string if you get a hit early on):

```
while True:
    question = input("ask me anything:")
    if question == "what is love":
        print("love is a emotion that makes me uneasy, i'm a inteligence not a human",name)
    elif question == "i want a dog":
        print("ask your mother, she knows what to do",name)
    elif question == "what is my name":
        print("your name is",name)
```

Of course, in this specific case, you could avoid the repeated tests by using a `dict` to perform a lookup, making an arbitrary number of prompts possible without repeated tests:

```
# Defined once up front
question_map = {
        'what is love': "love is a emotion that makes me uneasy, i'm a inteligence not a human",
        'i want a dog': 'ask your mother, she knows what to do',
        'what is my name': 'your name is',
        # Put as many more mappings as you want, code below doesn't change
        # and performance remains similar even for a million+ mappings
    }

print("hello,what is your name?")
name = input()
print("hello",name)

while True:
    question = input("ask me anything:")
    try:
        print(question_map[question], name)
    except KeyError:
        # Or check for "quit"/break the loop/alert to unrecognized question/etc.
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print("hello,what is your name?")
name = input()
print("hello",name)

while True:
    question = input("ask me anything:")
    if question == ("what is love"):
        print("love is a emotion that makes me uneasy, i'm a inteligence not a human",name)
    elif question == ("i want a dog"):
        print("ask your mother, she knows what to do",name)
    elif question == ("what is my name"):
        print("your name is",name)
```

Comment: Odd. I got hit by them, then they retracted their downvote after my edits (which added the `dict` based solution). I guess they want the answer to give a scalable solution if the number of prompts increases? I don't think it's worth a downvote to answer the question as asked, but to each their own, I guess.

Comment: I gave you an upvote. Looks like someone did for me too.

Answer (score -1):

Take out the `break`s.  Then have one of the options be "quit" with a `break`